# onbeforeunload not working in Windows Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have seen this issue posted before but onbeforeunload does not work for me in Windows Chrome.  I am using version 49.0.2623.112 m.  Here is my code:

```
<body onbeforeunload="handleBrowserCloseButton();">

function handleBrowserCloseButton() { 

//Call method by Ajax call
alert('Browser close button clicked');    

}
```

When I navigate away from the page or close the browser window, nothing happens.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually trying to execute some code to write out a file.  I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a non-void value from the callback function, otherwise you won't see a message dialog.

So you would need to change two things:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return handleBrowserCloseButton();">
```

and

```
function handleBrowserCloseButton() { 
    return 'Browser close button clicked';
}
```

Beside that you should use `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ... )` instead.

[MDN: WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload: Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes):

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog. In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." See bug 588292.

Because the functionality should net be misused to prevent the user form leaving the page, functions like `alert` or `confirm` won't work in the `onbeforeunload` callback.

[MDN: WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload: Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes):

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually trying to execute some code to write out a file.  I put the code in the function and it worked.

Comment: @Rod I don't say you can't execute code, but you can't use `alter` to display a message. If your actual code differs from your question then you need to show the code you try to execute and not something different.

Answer (score 0):

alert won't work on this event. Checkout section of notes in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: you may try out the suggestion on that link, which states: You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener] and the beforeunload [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload] event.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

fake();
}
```

Tested and working in all browsers.